# XMLParsing - convert string to NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Can someone please tell me what I need to to do resolve this

1. I have an object UserPrefs *userpref
2. There is a variable called userpref.userid, it is an NSNumber
3. I am parsing XML, everything here works good until I go to assign my "myxmluseridnumber" element to the userpref.userid

This is the error message.

Incompatible pointer types passing 'NSMutableString *_strong' to parameter of type 'NSNumber

```
    - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"User"]) {
            inItemElement = YES;
        }

        if (inItemElement && [elementName isEqualToString:@"myxmluseridnumber"]) {
            capturedCharacters = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
        }
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
       if(capturedCharacters != nil) {
           [capturedCharacters appendString:string];
       }
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

        if (inItemElement && [elementName isEqualToString:@"myxmluseridnumber"]) {
            NSLog(@"%@ - myxmlnumber", capturedCharacters);
            //This is what is producing my error
            userpref.userid = capturedCharacters;
            capturedCharacters = nil;
        }

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"User"]) {
            inItemElement = NO;
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since userid is an `NSNumber`, you should create an `NSNumber` from the string `capturedCharacters`

> userpref.userid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[capturedCharacters
>   intValue]];

Answer (score 0):

Replace your error-producing line with:

```
userpref.userid = [capturedCharacters intValue];
```

(assume your `capturedCharacters` is s `NSString`)